# Period in html/xml tags of jade template

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a jade template whose doctype is xml. I would like to create an xml tag that has a period in the name. I would like something like this to appear:

```
<This>
  <Tag>
    <HasA.InIt>Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!</HasA.InIt>
  </Tag>
</This>
```

Ordinarily, your jade template would be:

```
This
  Tag
    HasA.InIt Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!
```

Except, if you run this, you get:

```
<This>
  <Tag>
    <HasA class="InItPlease">don't ask why I need a period, I just do!</HasA>
  </Tag>
</This>
```

That's not even close to what I want. I've tried quite a few things with no luck. You can't escape the period (HasA\.InIt), and wrapping the tag in single or double quotes has no effect ([it seems like this used to work in an older version](http://scalate.github.io/scalate/documentation/jade-syntax.html#Weird_Element_Names:__code____code_element_code____code_)).

One thing that you can do is literally type the opening and closing xml tags. So your jade template would look something like:

```
This
  Tag
    <HasA.InIt>Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!</HasA.InIt>
```

Great! But if you have a variable that needs to appear rather than some simple value, this wont work:

```
This
  Tag
    - var str = "Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!"
    <HasA.InIt>= str</HasA.InIt>
```

yields:

```
<This>
  <Tag><HasA.InIt>= str</HasA.InIt>
  </Tag>
</This>
```

This leads me to believe that my little "fix" above is in fact not a fix at all, and I just got lucky. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Oh by the way, [Jade's website](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) has a nice little box where you can type in different things and see the outputs...nothing I've typed in has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this problem. `#{}` evaluates a javascript expression, so just toss a string in there.

```
This
  Tag
    - var str = "Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!"
    #{'HasA.InIt'}= str
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tag name as a variable worked for me:

```
This
  Tag
    - var tag = "HasA.InIt"
    - var str = "Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!"
    #{tag}=str
```

renders:

```html
<This>
  <Tag>
    <HasA.InIt>Please don't ask why I need a period, I just do!</HasA.InIt>
  </Tag>
</This>
```

Comment: This works! I'd upvote you but my reputation is too low :( Thanks a lot!